# My android app crashes with low probability when it call system gallery to open image

Tags: android, image-processing, nullpointerexception, gallery

I have published an image editing app to android market , user can open image with system gallery,but they may fail to do this with low probability on some phones, other phones run ok.I searched many times over internet, but no answer.I can reproduce this problem on my rooted phone with low probability , but another unrooted phone have no this problem, it runs always normally.
The error log is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rainbow.jean.imageedit/com.rainbow.jean.imageedit.EditActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:171)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5453)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3612)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3477)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3453)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:371)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2001)
at com.rainbow.jean.imageedit.EditActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5224)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
... 11 more
```

and my codes to call gallery follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,                           activity.getResources().getString(R.string.image_open_intent_string)), 1);
```

Can anyone tell me the reason? I am very appreciated.

Comment: can you please post EditActivity code ?

Comment: code is very simple, btn = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.open_button);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                   
                    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            activity.getResources().getString(R.string.image_open_intent_string)), EditActivity.SELECT_AN_IMAGE_OPEN);

Comment: post you code in question not as comment.

Comment: The last part of question is codes which call gallery, you may see it. onCreate also very simple, just setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this is happening because you are getting a URL instead and not a local image location? something like getting a picture from Dropbox or Google drive.

If this is the case then probably you can try this,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
}
```

Or handle the URL in some other way which is something I haven't done yet :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your suggestion,but it can't resolve my problem.The image which I wanted to open is really on my sdcard, and usually it can't be opened at the fist time , but it can be opened at the second and later time.

Comment: Now I found this problem was caused by a mobile saftey software called "lbe security", Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself.This problem was caused by low memory device.These devices has small memory and maybe have a lot of background process, so when system gallery is called , my activity is killed by system, it is recreated after that. My codes handle saveInstanceState with some bug, so it crashes.Hope this post may help others.